# If $1835^2 \equiv 1 \mod{7}$ and $1986^3 \equiv 0 \mod{7}$, why is $1835^2 + 1986^3 \equiv 0 \mod{7}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm not sure what I'm missing; I've tried to apply Fermat's Little Theorem to prove that $1835^{1910} + 1986^{2061} \equiv 0 \mod{7}$.

Edit: OK, so my question now becomes: why is my calculator is telling me that $7 \mid 1986^3$?

```
input: 1986^3
output: 7833173256
input: ANS ÷ 7
output: 1119024751
```

Comment: A quick divisibility check reveals $986-1=985=140×7+5$ is not a multiple of $7$.  So $1986$ is not one one either and the hypothesis fails.

Comment: You shouldn't change the question after it already has answers.

Comment: Your calculator rounded $1119024750\frac67$ to $1119024751$

Comment: You should reduce $1835$ and $1986$ modulo $7$ as the first step. If they come out as $0, \pm 1$ you have saved yourself even having to use Fermat (you can surely raise these to any positive integer power), and you have, in any event reduced the computational size of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using a calculator which rounds $\frac {1986^3}{7}$ to $1119024751$ and gives the false impression that  $1986^3$ is a multiple of $7$

Do the calculation by hand and you see  $\frac {1986^3}{7}$ is not an integer.

Comment: What a bummer! Isn't this a basic flaw in calculator design? What's the oportunity cost of not rounding up in this particular case?

Comment: Calculators are for checking calculations, not for doing them. Especially some that don't have order of operations built in.  Also did you try subtracting the larger part of that off? Some calculators hold more digits than they can display and so round displayed answers when needed.

Answer (score 2):

$1986^3$ can't be $0$ because $1986\equiv 5\bmod 7$ and $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z$ is a field.

Namely, $1986^3\equiv 5^3\equiv -2^3\equiv -1\mod 7$ and $1835\equiv1\bmod 7$, so what is true is that
$$1835^{1910}+1986^3\equiv 1+(-1)\equiv 0\mod 7.$$

Comment: Did you mean mod $7$ where you wrote mod $8$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Yes. One of my many  typos… Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

$$1986 \equiv 5  ( mod \ 7) \\ 1986^{3} \equiv 5^{3} \equiv  \color{#c00}{6} (mod \ 7) $$

Answer (score 0):

$\bmod 7\!:\,\ 1835\equiv 1,\ 1986\equiv\color{#c00}{ -2}\,$ (not $\,0),\,$ so

$\begin{align}\qquad\qquad &1835^{\large k}\! + 1986^{\,\large 3\,+\,6n}\\
\equiv &\ \ \ \ \ \ 1^{\large k}\! + (\color{#c00}{-2})^{\large 3(1+2n)}\\
\equiv &\ \ \ \ \ \ 1\ + (\,-1\,)^{\large\ 1+2n}\equiv 0\end{align}$

**Edit** $ $ Regarding the updated question, you don't need to use a calculator since it is easy mentally: $\!\bmod 7:\,\ 1986 = 2(10)^{\large 3}-14 \equiv 2(3^{\large 3})-0\equiv \color{#c00}{2(-1)}.\,$  In fact $\,10^{\large 3}\!+1 = 7\cdot 11\cdot 13\,$ so we can use $10^{\large 3}\equiv -1\,$ when computing mod any factor of $\,10^{\large 3}\!+1 = 1001,\ $ e.g. $\,77 = 7\cdot 11$.